# Resize parent element when inner one is dragged. (jqueryUI draggable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bDpLB/4/)

When `#right` element is dragged, I want to resize its parent. My example works incorrectly and I'm failing to comprehend why. Any hints how to fix it?

Just in case, what I'm trying to do here is to create a resizable scroll similar to [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock). But for now, I'm only interested in the right element.

Comment: Looks very much like the behavior of draggable depends on the parent's dimensions and that it does not like the item's parent being resized mid-way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is as follows (note the #left and #right changes in SCSS):

SCSS:

```css
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

#nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    cursor: move;
}
#left {
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;
    background: #a9a9a9;
    cursor: w-resize;
    &:hover {
        background: #999;
    }
}
#right {
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0px;
    background: #a9a9a9;
    cursor: e-resize;
    &:hover {
        background: #999;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var cont = $("#container")
var nav = $("#nav")
var left = $("#left")
var right = $("#right")

nav.draggable({
    containment: cont
});

right.draggable({
    containment: cont,
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        nav.width(ui.position.left);
    }
});
```

The only problem was you were getting too fancy with your JavaScript.  The ui.position.left had all the information you needed.  All I did was change the content from floating to position:absolute;

Comment: Hmm, this looks nice. Didn't think about changing the CSS at the first place.

Comment: Oh you <3  You flatter me *blushes*  But in all seriousness: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the good ol' pure JavaScript to do that
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cCvGD/

```
var oriX = 0,
    oriW = 0,
    mousedown = false;
right.mousedown(function (e) {
    oriX = $(this).offset().left;             //store the initial x and width
    oriW = nav.width();
    mousedown = true;                         //mousedown sets to true
    e.stopPropagation();                      //prevent nav from being dragged
})
$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    if(mousedown == true) {                   //only when mouse is down (dragging)
        nav.width(oriW + (e.clientX - oriX)); //calculate the width
    }
}).mouseup(function () {
    mousedown = false;                        //mousedown sets to false
});
```

Both left and right: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cCvGD/1/

Comment: You can definitely use jQuery here.  There's a solution.

Comment: @GrahamRobertson - Of course you can, but it might be cumbersome to do since `draggable` seems to rely on the size of the parent element.

Comment: see the answer I provided.  draggable gives the position relative to the container it's inside.  It just required changing the right and left elements to position:absolute; instead of floats and simplifying the JavaScript to change the width to whatever the ui.position.left was.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the you are changing the width of your *nav* container, and this is moving out the *right* element.  So while you are dragging it, it moves twice as far.

You can get get around this by resetting the location of your *right* element in the dragable method

```
right.draggable({
    containment: cont,
    drag: function(e, ui){
        dragged = ui.position.left;
        nav.width(originNavWidth + dragged);
        ui.position.left = nav.position.left;
    }
})
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/vf4eS

Comment: It doesn't work when the width of `nav` to bigger than it was.

Comment: Right, this still has the issue of resetting back to the original width with each drag.  Seems like Graham had the answer with changing the css to not use floats.